# Groovy swingbuilder events for textField

Tags: swing, events, groovy, swingbuilder

I have the following Code:

```
textField(id: 'programfilter', actionPerformed: { println("execute some action") })
```

However, the actionPerformed-closure is only called when the textField has the focus and enter is pressed. What do I have to do so that the closure is called on different events e.g. clicking into the textField, selecting text in it or simply on every update of its text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that leveraging [*closure coercion*](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-semantics.html#closure-coercion). Just a quick example to demonstrate:

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder
import java.awt.event.*
import javax.swing.event.*
import javax.swing.WindowConstants as WC

SwingBuilder.build() {
    frame(title:'Swing Listener example', size:[300,100], 
            visible:true, defaultCloseOperation:WC.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) {
        gridLayout(cols: 2, rows: 0)
        label 'Input text: '
        input = textField(columns:10, actionPerformed: { echo.text = input.text.toUpperCase() })        
        label 'Echo: '
        echo = label()
        input.document.addDocumentListener(
            [insertUpdate: { echo.text = input.text },
             removeUpdate: { echo.text = input.text },
             changedUpdate: { e -> println e }] as DocumentListener)

        input.addFocusListener(
            [focusGained: { e -> println "Focus gained: $e.cause"},
             focusLost: {e -> println "Focus lost: $e.cause"}] as FocusListener)

        input.addCaretListener({ e ->  println "Caret event: $e"})
    }
}
```